# Processing changed files in WAF script

Tags: python, waf

Is it possible to write a WAF function in wscript file, which will be called while building on every changed file?

I want to be able to do the following:

1. Process all input `.hpp` files by a custom Python function and output them to build folder. If such file was changed I want to process it and update its definition in output folder.
2. Process all input `.hpp` files by an external script and output the resutls to build folder.

**UPDATE:**

To explain: I want for each changed file run an `fun1(file)` function, which will read the file, modify it and return modified version, which should be outputed to the destination directory.

Answer (score 1):

Processing only modified files is one of the main feature of WAF ^^

To execute your python function, you can do something like that :

```
top = '.'
out = 'build'


def configure(conf):
    pass

def build(bld):

    def fun1(input_file):

        # whatever

        return output_file_content_as_string

    def process(task):

        for src_node in task.inputs:

            src = src_node.abspath()
            tgt = src_node.get_bld()

            out = fun1(src)

            tgt.write(out)

        return 0 # everything ok

    bld(
        rule   = process,
        source = ['myfile.hpp', 'myfile2.hpp', ],
    )
```

This will call fun1 on myfile.hpp, etc. and output in build dir only on modified files.

By default waf manage a signature for every source to detect any change, and process it only if the signature change ...

Comment: Thanks, but I want to process the file before copying - lets say run a Python function on it - is it possible?

Comment: Yes. In fact the subst feature do exactly that if you do not use the is_copy=True parameter. It can substitute something in source to get the target. What do you want to do exactly with your file ? By the way, update your question to make it clearer/more detailled, that's SO way.

Comment: I want to process it with my custom Python function (look at the update in the question). The function could read the file, parse it, modify and output the modified version - I want to do it FOR EACH modified file.

Comment: still no answer how to run my python function on each changed file :(

Comment: I think what I propose will do.